# Urls on nested web application under IIS Web Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have website running under IIS 7.5.
It has child web application 'WebA'. Path to that site is 'localhost/weba'
WebA has some pages with anchors on it, anchor urls are like '/UserDetails.aspx'.
When I click on this anchors, browser redirects me to localhost/userDetails.aspx instead of localhost/weba/userdetails.aspx.

I have working example under IIS 6, but have no idea what option should be set to make it work under IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You should try

`<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/UserDetails.aspx" runat="server">My link</asp:HyperLink>`

and it should redirect to localhost/weba/userdetails.aspx.

In Javascript you can use the value of

`var myUrl = '<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/UserDetails.aspx") %>';`

Basically you need to add a '~/' to the beginning of your path because it's the application relative path and not the path of the root domain.

Comment: yeah, thanks, that is the option, but there is a lot of existing links in project at the moment and do that convertions is not very simple.

Comment: True... but programming isn't very simple. Moreover, you can write a C# console application that uses regex to match the old URLs and replace them with the new (and correct) ones. It'll be a good exercise for you too! :)